# How to enter survey coordinates into parcel fabric traverse grid?

Tags: land-survey, parcel-fabric

I have a survey that only gives me the coordinate points for a parcel I need to draw into the parcel fabric. I am used to seeing bearings and distances - how do I take these coordinate points and turn them into bearings and distances without teaching myself a bunch of trig? Alternately, is there a tool in the parcel fabric wherein I can enter the points instead of the bearing and distance to create the parcel?

On a side note, does anyone have any recommendations for books/websites/resources that would help me learn about basics of surveying (as a user) to help me with math stuff like this in the future? Preferably at a "For Dummies" or ELI5 level...
[image: Point Table of Survey]

Comment: Personally I would just dummy, brute-force this and just plot the points in the table, and then just draw construction lines between the points. Finally import the lines as construction lines into the fabric. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-parcels/copying-and-pasting-linework-as-construction-lines.htm